# WPF data binding change the column width in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a simple Grid with 3 columns

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NavigationWidth}"  />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid> 

  <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                      ResizeDirection="Columns" 
                      Background="Silver"                      
                      Width="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

<ContentControl x:Name="navigationView"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
<ContentControl x:Name="workspaceView" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"  />


// The NavigationWidth is belongs to the ViewModel

  public int NavigationWidth
  {
     get{ return _navigationWidth; }
     set{
            _navigationWidth = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("NavigationWidth");
        }
 }
```

So based setup above, depends on where the user navigation to, the codes try to set the width of the first column of the grid.
 Everything works fine if the user does not manually change the width.

Is there anyway  the code can overwrite the width that was set by the user?

Thanks,

Austin

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway the code can overwrite the width that was set by the user?

Yes by setting the value NavigationWidth at the desired time/location as long as the binding is two way such as:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NavigationWidth, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Comment: As long as the user does not change the width by moving the grid slitter, the codes above works just fine.

Comment: @AustinTX Change the property of the grid to not allow resizing.

Comment: But the user wants to change the width manually if they want to.

Comment: @AustinTX I am not understanding...what is the "Not working" fine situation which you mention when a user changes it? Is the value not right or visibly something unexpected happens?

Comment: Not working mean the codes from the ViewModel has no affect to the UI once the user manual move the grid slitter.

Comment: Facing similar problem also with the Grid control. Column width can no longer be changed dynamically, once the user has moved a Gridsplitter to manually re-size any of the columns. It does not matter if data-binding was done through triggers or directly to control element.

Comment: @reexmonkey was the binding target changed? Can you verify that it is the original referenced item? If the reference changes, InotifyPropertyChanged is still subscribed to the old object, which will never change and is now `pinned` in memory never to be cleaned up.